# Use onclick event in parent or child element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

A little back story to get my situation:
My colleague who monitors the GA stuff tells me it isn't firing when trying to track how many are clicking on what, on our website. Now I don't have access to the google account to check if my changes are working or not and she's currently sick (and no my company doesn't want GA accounts being shared for whatever reason)

So I thought I'd come here and ask while I wait. Currently the GA was set up like this, and I wanted to know if it matters where the onclick is? Should it be in the anchor tag in this situation? or leaving it in that div is okay?

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><div onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'PledgeSheet');"><a href="this_tool" target="_blank">Pledge Sheet</a></div></td>

     <td><div onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'StepByStepGuide');"><a href="this_tool" target="_blank">Step by Step Guide</a></div></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'SampleBudget');"><a href="this_tool" target="_blank">Sample Budget</a></div></td>
    <td><div onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'LawnSign');"><a href="this_tool" target="_blank">Lawn Sign</a></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'EventPlanningChart');"><a href="hthis_tool" target="_blank">Event Planning Chart</a></div></td>
    <td><div onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Click', 'ParticipantCentre', 'FundraisingThermometer');"><a href="hthis_tool" target="_blank">Fundraising Thermometer</a></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know who made or set it up this way but it looks wrong to me, mainly because I don't put divs inside a td because of layout problems.

What I changed it to is this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="this_tool" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'PledgeSheet');">Pledge Sheet</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="this_tool" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'StepByStepGuide');">Step by Step Guide</a>
          </div>
[...]
```

Is this a better set up? could that be why it wasn't firing? The GA code itself is correct as we used it before for other pages, those pages had it set up a little different, like this (but still targeted the child element span):

```
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <a class="navLink" href="website" target="_blank"><span class="navTextWhite" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'VolunteerHomepage', 'navbar', 'signup');">Sign me up!</span></a>
                        </li>
```

Because I saw that ^ I wanted to know if it mattered whether the onclick was in the parent or child element for GA tracking.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The onClick must be on the A href

Comment: Is it because the div isn't what's being clicked it's the `a href`, so onclick should be on that `a href`, right?

Comment: at face value what you originally had should work. It sounds like there is other event listener code attached to the links that prevent the event from bubbling up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onClick` should really be on the element which you want to track i.e. the `<a href>` tag.

If it's on the div the event will fire when ever there's a click within the div, which may not necessarily be on the `<a href>` tag. See the two elements in the snippet below as an example. Clicking anywhere on the second `<div>` will fire the event.

```js
  function ga() {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
```

```css
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #aff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
  <div class="top-container">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="col-6">
      <a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'PledgeSheet');">Pledge Sheet</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Participant_Centre', 'Click', 'PledgeSheet2');">
      <a href="#">Pledge Sheet 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your tracking code may not work because the web browser will stop executing JavaScript on the current page once a new page starts to load. The [Sending Data to Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#knowing_when_the_hit_has_been_sent) section of the API documentation has detailed information on how to ensure in so far as it is possible that the event is successfully recorded.

Comment: awesome! Thanks Dan, this is exactly what I wanted to know. And thank you for that sending data to google link I couldn't find that info for some reason, I guess I was using the wrong words when googling lol. This is super useful thanks again!